# SQL Select with multiple column result with conditions

Tags: sql, select, subquery

Please help me with this SQL select query. It works as three select statements but I need to make it into one statement

```
select (loan_amount + origination_fee) column1 from Table
where transaction_type='A'

select (stock_price + broker_fee) column2 from Table
where transaction_type='B'

select (taxable_amount + miscellaneous) column3 from Table
where transaction_type='C'
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT   (
            SELECT  (loan_amount + origination_fee)
            FROM    table
            WHERE   transaction_type = 'A'
         ) AS A
        ,(
            SELECT  (stock_price + broker_fee)
            FROM    table
            WHERE   transaction_type = 'B'
         ) AS B
        ,(
            SELECT  (taxable_amount + miscellaneous)
            FROM    table
            WHERE   transaction_type = 'C'
         ) AS C
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Sample data would help your question.

Comment: In addition to sample data and desired results, please also add a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when transaction_type='A' then loan_amount + origination_fee end as A,
       case when transaction_type='B' then stock_price + broker_fee end as B,
       case when transaction_type='C' then taxable_amount + miscellaneous end as C 
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when transaction_type='A' then loan_amount + origination_fee else NULL end as A,
       case when transaction_type='B' then stock_price + broker_fee else NULL end as B,
       case when transaction_type='C' then taxable_amount + miscellaneous else NULL end as C 
from your_table
where transaction_type in ('A', 'B', 'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want.  But if you want one row with the *sum* of the three values, then:

```
select sum(case when transaction_type = 'A' then loan_amount + origination_fee end) as A,
       sum(case when transaction_type = 'B' then loan_amount + origination_fee end) as B,
       sum(case when transaction_type = 'C' then loan_amount + origination_fee end) as C
from t;
```